# Is UnsafeMutableRawPointer copyMemory(from:byteCount:) a synchronous operation?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, memory-management

Quick question (as I cannot find this in the documentation):
Is `copyMemory(from:byteCount:)` on an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` a synchronous or asynchronous operation? Or in other words: Is it guaranteed that copying the memory is finished when proceeding after the `copyMemory` call?

Comment: Is there any reason you would believe it were asynchronous? If it were, there would be a completion handler. is there some other similar method you're thinking of that is asynchronous?

Comment: Your title and your question body are asking different questions. Syncrhonization is about whether or not the copying is done in an exclusive region that guarantees other threads wont try to modify it concurrently (causing race conditions). Synchronicity is about whether operation blocks until completion, or if it returns quickly and does the operation at some later point, without holding everything else up.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: Thanks for the hint, it was a typo in the title.

Comment: @RobNapier: I am almost a hundred percent certain that it is synchronous. No completion handler available being one reason. Just want to make absolutely sure when using it in code.

Comment: @Wizard It's synchronous, but not synchronized.